# Django how to split a TextField to create content?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I have a model named Name, with the following code:

```
class Name(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile)
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    multinombres = models.TextField()
```

I want that if you choose CharField just enter a name string text, but if you choose TextField you can enter multiple names text strings one per line.

I have the idea to do something like:

```
multinombres.splitlines()
```

How and where do I implement it?

I am not sure or understanding well, if this I have to work in **views.py** or where to from any form that is entered work with this **TextField**

Comment: You want new lines in the `TextField()`, or when it's displayed in an HTML file?

Comment: When you enter the form to create, split should happen, to be created

Comment: Can you post your form please? You could add it in the `clean()` method.

Comment: {% extends "cfdipanel/base_users.html" %}
{% block content %}
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <div>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <h1>Nuevos Nombres</h1>
        <form method="POST" class="name-form">{% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_p }}
            <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Agregar</button>
            <p>Por favor copie y pegue los nombres en el campo de texto, uno por linea.</p>
        </form>
    </div>
        {% else %}
        <p>porfavor logeate</p>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}

Comment: I meant your `forms.py` form. Not the setup in your template :P

Comment: from django import forms

from .models import Name

class NameForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Name
        fields = ('multinombres',)